# using rand and the File superglobal php?

Tags: php, file, random

I saw this code in a tutorial.

Is it pre-fixing a random number to the file name?

```
$file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Comment: yeah, it does that.

Comment: Yeah. Prepending a random between 1000 and 10000 to the file name with `-` in the middle of them.

Comment: You are literally answering your own question. You could have verified it by running it. I don't think this is a good Q&A-style question, please see [ask].

Comment: OKay so is not 100% necessary in order to upload a file and the author of the tutorial is just using it to prevent duplicate file names. The tutorial I am lookin  at the code did not run so I was unable to verify it's purpose.now i understand stand the purpose of each line I should be able to implement a working version. I think it's a valid question. I had difficulty understanding a line of code and asked a specific question about that line ?